# How to manipulate the range of rand() in PHP?

Tags: php, random

Okay so i'm making a little gambling site for practice and I wanted to have the option to "Roll High" or "Roll Low."

For example: If the bettor chooses 20% win chance, and they choose roll high, they win on 80-100.  If they choose roll low, they win on 1-20.  Right now with the code I have below it's always rolling "Low" as in 1-20 if the win chance is 20%.

I feel like this isn't all-that-hard to do but it's confusing me. :S  Oh and if you're going to give an example please use the code below except use `isset($_POST['start2'])` and change whatever else needs to be changed to make it work.

Thanks.

```
$rand = rand(100, 10000)/100;

if(isset($_POST['start1'])) {

if(isset($_POST['bet'], $_POST['pay'], $_POST['profit'], $_POST['chance'])) {

   if($rand < $_POST['chance']) {

 echo '<h3>You rolled a <strong>' .$rand. ' </strong> out of 100 on the percentile dice!  You won!</h3>';

}

else if($rand > $_POST['chance']) { echo '<h3>You rolled a <strong>' .$rand. '</strong> out of 100 on the percentile dice!  You lost...</h3>'; }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are getting the high/low choice from the user's POST. Get that and then, if they select high, compare to 100-chance.

For example:

```
  $rand = rand(0,100);
  $chance = $_POST['chance'];
  $roll = "L";     //should come from a POST variable set to H or L

  if($roll == 'H')
      $win = ($rand + $chance) - 100;
  else
      $win = $chance - $rand;

  if($win > 0)
      echo "You rolled a " . $rand . " You win!";
  else
      echo "You rolled a " . $rand . " You lose.";
```

Comment: I'm appreciative of your help but I'm afraid that wouldn't work.  If they choose 50% and roll a 15 it outputs a negative number.

Comment: I'm using that code and I still have the same problem.  When I click Roll High it rolls low too..

Comment: I created a php fiddle with the code above here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7kh-5bs You can change the values of $chance and $roll and run it to test the algorithm. Then paste it into your page and use your POST values.